# Separating custom tags' contents using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I need a snippet of code that will grab all values surrounded by tags in a String in Java and return them as a string array if the tags' names match a series of keywords. The tags are all just normal text words surrounded by a "<>" and an end tag surrounded by "" for each tag created.

Ex. of read in text-

```
  <name>stuff<name/>
  <locations>example of text<locations/>
  <storybattles>more text somehow<storybattles/>
  <maincharacter>characters n stuff <maincharacter/>
//continues on with random tag text values
```

returns-

```
"stuff"
"example of text"
"more text somehow"
"characters n stuff"
```

preferable use case-

```
String inputText="pretend there are tags in here";
//Please pretend I added several keywordsd to the keywords list
ArrayList<String> keywords=new ArrayList<String>(); 
String[] allTheAnswers=kindStackOverflowMentorMethod(inputText,keywords);
```

While I can do this by myself with my limited knowledge of Regex, I am just cringing as I know this can be done a much better way. If you include an explanation for each part of the regex expression you use(or whatever solution a brilliant mind might cook up) then you get extra points from me.

Comment: I did try my own methods, but it was essentially me hacking and slashing through the process using .split, .remove, etc. I just needed a tiny snippet of understandable regex to get my feet on the ground...or off of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of how I would do it:

```
private static final String DATA = "<name>stuff<name/>\n" +
        "  <locations>example of text<locations/>\n" +
        "  <storybattles>more text somehow<storybattles/>\n" +
        "  <maincharacter>characters n stuff <maincharacter/>";

private static final List<String> KEYWORDS = Arrays.asList(
        new String[]{"name", "locations"});

private static final String PATTERN = "<%1$s>(.+?)<%1$s/>";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String keyword : KEYWORDS) {
        String tempPattern = String.format(PATTERN, keyword);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(tempPattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(DATA);

        while(matcher.find()){
            strs.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

[**Regex101 Fiddle**](https://regex101.com/r/lZ8xR3/2)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works just as intended, now can you tell me how "%1$" and "s" are working between the "<" and ">"?

Comment: That value is a placeholder for `String.format()`, it is not part of the regex. Before building the Pattern object, I change that value to a literal string like "name", thus the regex becomes `<name>(.+?)<name/>`. Each iteration over the keyword list will change the regex to the current keyword between `<>`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String inputText=" <name>stuff<name/>\n"+
        " <locations>example of text<locations/>\n"+
        " <storybattles>more text somehow<storybattles/>\n"+
        " <maincharacter>characters n stuff <maincharacter/>";

    //Please pretend I added several keywordsd to the keywords list
    ArrayList<String> keywords=new ArrayList<>(); 
    keywords.add("locations");
    keywords.add("maincharacter");

    //Call the function
    ArrayList<String> allTheAnswers=kindStackOverflowMentorMethod(inputText,keywords);

}

public static ArrayList<String> kindStackOverflowMentorMethod(String inputText, ArrayList<String> keywords){
    ArrayList<String> values=new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)>(.*?)<(?:\\1)\\/>").matcher(inputText);
    while (m.find()){
        if (keywords.indexOf(m.group(1)) > -1)  {
            values.add(m.group(2));            
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

**REGEX EXPLANATION**

```
<                   # match < literally
([a-z][a-z0-9]*)    # first capturing group - match TAG name
                      should start with a letter, followed by
                      0 or more letters or numbers
>                   # match > literally 
(.*?)               # 2nd capturing group - match content surrounded by TAGs
                      non-greedy match
<                   # match < literally
(?:\1)              # non-capturing group - match previous matched TAG name
\/>                 # match /> literally
```

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you so much for the through explanation. So "?:\1" means grab a previously matched series of characters? Because that and changing the tags name to be searched were stopping me from moving forward. Also if I can ask another question, does the loop essentially check to see if the key word is inside of the text, or does it find the location and use that to locate specific values?

Comment: Non-capturing group is donated by `(?:pattern)`, and `\1` means previously matched series of characters. `if (keywords.indexOf(m.group(1)) > -1)` checks if the keyword is in the current matched group 1; if true, add the corresponding value to the list.This is one-on-one pair, so there is no need to find the location. :)